# I need to compile the output summary statistics from a function in a loop

Tags: r, loops, model, summary

I am processing data where I measured height (y) over a number of days of year (x). I fit that to a Weibull growth function and got the summary parameters for the Weibull curve.

```
library(drc)
x <- c(159, 165, 176, 179, 187, 199, 208, 222)
y <- c(0.2854, 0.3932, 0.8402, 0.9431, 1.5476, 2.2, 2.576, 3.088)
onetwoone_seven <- data.frame(x,y)
model <- drm(y ~ x, fct = W2.4(), data = onetwoone_seven)
sumamry(model)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Model fitted: Weibull (type 2) (4 parms)

Parameter estimates:

----------------Estimate Std. Error  t-value   p-value    
b:(Intercept)   9.31120    1.42121   6.5516  0.002806 ** 

c:(Intercept)  -0.23603    0.21622  -1.0916  0.336359    

d:(Intercept)   3.18323    0.15044  21.1593 2.949e-05 ***

e:(Intercept) 194.82041    1.84423 105.6375 4.815e-08 ***
```

The issue is that on each day of year i measured the height of ~1000 plots. So I had to loop the function for every plot. What i need to know is how to include a summary statement in the loop that creates an output that compiles the summary results for every plot.

The loop is below

```
my_data = height2018ordered
row_range = unique(my_data$row_range)

num_obs = length(row_range)

WeibullFunction <- function (df){drm(df$canopy_height ~ df$doy, fct = W2.4())}

results <- vector('list', num_obs)

for (i in seq_len(num_obs)) {
  one_day = row_range[i]
  one_day_data = subset(my_data, row_range == one_day)
  results[[i]] = WeibullFunction(one_day_data)
```

So i think i need the summary parameter for every 'one_day_data'.

I would appreciate help trying to figure out how to get the Weibull summary statements compiled by plot. Below, I have included sample data from three plots 1_2, 1_3 and 1_4.

```
dput(my_data[1:27, c(2,3,4,5,6)])
structure(list(first_row = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), range = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4), canopy_height = c(0.2947, 0.493, 0.8598, 0.9698, 
1.5641, 1.8774, 2.1465, 2.5994, 2.953, 0.1426, 0.3384, 0.6749, 
0.7694, 1.0454, 1.199, 1.2893, 1.527, 2.0869, 0.3079, 0.4901, 
0.8527, 0.8918, 1.3971, 1.5897, 1.9244, 2.1692, 2.6118), row_range = c("1 _ 2", 
"1 _ 2", "1 _ 2", "1 _ 2", "1 _ 2", "1 _ 2", "1 _ 2", "1 _ 2", 
"1 _ 2", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", 
"1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 3", "1 _ 4", "1 _ 4", "1 _ 4", "1 _ 4", 
"1 _ 4", "1 _ 4", "1 _ 4", "1 _ 4", "1 _ 4"), doy = c(159, 165, 
176, 179, 187, 194, 199, 207, 222, 159, 165, 176, 179, 187, 194, 
199, 207, 222, 159, 165, 176, 179, 187, 194, 199, 207, 222)), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: We really need a sample of your data, preferably using `dput()`. It appears that you could use `split()` to split the data frame into a list of data frames, one for each day. Then use `lapply()` to apply your function to each of those days and return a list of the model results for each day. Using `lapply()` on that list with `summary()` would give you a list of the summary results for each day.

Comment: I have included sample data at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. First, split `my_data` by `row_range` to get `my_data_split`, a list of three data frames:

```
my_data_split <- split(my_data, my_data$row_range)
```

Now compute the distribution for each data frame to get `my_data_WB`, a list with three lists containing the results of `drm()`:

```
my_data_WB <- lapply(my_data_split, function(x) drm(canopy_height~doy, data=x, fct=W2.4()))
```

Finally pass those results to `summary` to get a third list:

```
my_data_sum <- lapply(my_data_WB, summary)
my_data_sum
#  $`1 _ 2`
#  
# Model fitted: Weibull (type 2) (4 parms)
# 
# Parameter estimates:
# 
#                 Estimate Std. Error  t-value   p-value    
# b:(Intercept)  10.339642   1.100705   9.3937 0.0002306 ***
# c:(Intercept)  -0.072540   0.138456  -0.5239 0.6227178    
# d:(Intercept)   3.004511   0.080538  37.3057 2.607e-07 ***
# e:(Intercept) 193.683494   1.135072 170.6354 1.312e-10 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error:
# 
#  0.05622148 (5 degrees of freedom)

              .  .  .  .
```

Followed by the results for the rest of the groups. The results can be accessed by number within the list or name:

```
my_data_WB[[1]]   # or my_data_WB[["1 _ 2"]]
# 
# A 'drc' model.
# 
# Call:
# drm(formula = canopy_height ~ doy, data = x, fct = W2.4())
# 
# Coefficients:
# b:(Intercept)  c:(Intercept)  d:(Intercept)  e:(Intercept)  
#      10.33964       -0.07254        3.00451      193.68349
```

There are several ways to get the table you describe. The simplest gets the values when computing the distribution:

```
my_data_coef <- lapply(my_data_split, function(x) coef(drm(canopy_height~doy, data=x, fct=W2.4())))
my_data_tbl <- do.call(rbind, my_data_coef)
my_data_tbl
#       b:(Intercept) c:(Intercept) d:(Intercept) e:(Intercept)
# 1 _ 2     10.339642   -0.07254013      3.004511      193.6835
# 1 _ 3      2.279858   -2.02855530      7.136699      280.0824
# 1 _ 4      8.398488   -0.17854704      2.746110      194.5615
```

Alternatively you can get the table from the list of results:

```
t(sapply(my_data_WB, coef))
```

If you want to keep only the letters:

```
colnames(my_data_tbl) <- substr(colnames(my_data_tbl), 1, 1)
my_data_tbl
#               b           c        d        e
# 1 _ 2 10.339642 -0.07254013 3.004511 193.6835
# 1 _ 3  2.279858 -2.02855530 7.136699 280.0824
# 1 _ 4  8.398488 -0.17854704 2.746110 194.5615
```

Comment: That gets me incredibly close to where i want to be. I also need a way to modify and tabulate the summary results so it looks something like:  row_range, b_value, c_value, d_value, _e value. Ultimately i'd like those four parameters in a list for every row_range. I need to use that list in another piece of analysis software.